# How to specify gem version to install and omit documentation downloading when using bundler?

Tags: ruby, version, bundler

I used following command to install mysql2 gem:

```
gem install mysql2 --no-ri --no-rdoc -v 0.3.11 -- --with-mysql-dir=C:\mysql-connector
```

It executed succesfully.

Now I want to use bunder to achieve the same result.

I didn't used bunder before and I am watching tutorial now at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hy5x8aGKrrw

From the tutorial I know how to specify command line parameter `--with-mysql-dir=C:\mysql-connector` and install mysql2 gem. This is with two commands in the following way:

```
bundle config build.mysql2 --with-mysql-dir=C:\mysql-connector
bundle install
```

It is OK. But I can not realize how to specify following command line parameters from initial command: `--no-ri --no-rdoc -v 0.3.11`.

How to specify them?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you simply can't, in the [documentation](http://bundler.io/man/bundle-config.1.html) is not mentioned these parameters. The only way is through the `gem` command